# How to move towards dependency injection with singleton class

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection

I am trying to learn to write Testable code in Java. I have seen a lot of links saying a singleton class isn't great to implement if I want to do unit testing. So here is what I am trying to solve. I have a class which sends HTTP Requests (HTTPRequest class). I want this class to worry about which protocol to use (TLSv1.2 etc). I have multiple other classes which just calls HTTPRequest class with body, URL, etc.

The way I approached it was that HTTPRequest can be a singleton class since there is no need to create multiple instances of the same thing. The protocol for the entire project will be same and needs to be set only once.

This is how my HTTPRequest looks like.

```
public class HTTPRequest {
    private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
    private HttpGet httpGet;
    private HttpPut httpPut;
    private HttpPost httpPost;

    HTTPRequest(CloseableHttpClient a, HttpGet b, HttpPut c, HttpPost d) {
        httpClient = a;
        httpGet = b;
        httpPut = c;
        httpPost = d;
    }

    public HTTPResponse getRequest(url) {
        //Do some processing with httpClient & httpGet to send the request
    }
}
```

Now from the classes which require HTTPRequest is there a way to call getRequest, but using only one object? I read something about dependency injection, but I am not really able to figure out how I should do it.

How should I modify the code so that it is testable as well?

Comment: Why are you passing `HttpGet`, `HttpPut`, etc as parameters in the constructor?

Comment: @alayor I want to mock the responses for HttpGet. Since I don't want it to actually my server.

Comment: But could you pass `HttpGet` in `getRequest` method?

Comment: @alayor Yes I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is remove the constructor in `HTTPRequest` class and then create `protected` methods called `getHttpGet()`, `getHttpPut`, etc.

```
public class HTTPRequest {

    public HTTPResponse getRequest(url) {
        //Do some processing with httpClient & httpGet to send the request
      getHttpGet(url).call();
    }

    protected CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
      return new CloseableHttpClient();
    }

    protected HttpGet getHttpGet(String url) {
      return new HttpGet(url);
    }

    protected HttpPost getHttpPost(String url) {
      return new HttpPost(url);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, you can create a `HttpRequestMock` class that inherits from `HttpRequest` and override `getHttp*` methods.

```
public class HTTPRequestMock extends HttpRequest {

    @Override
    protected CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
      //return mock
      return new CloseableHttpClientMock();
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpGet getHttpGet(String url) {
      //return mock
      return new HttpGetMock(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpPost getHttpPost(String url) {
      //return mock
      return new HttpPostMock(url);
    }

    ...
}
```

Last, you can inject `HttpRequest` or `HttpRequestMock` accordingly in your unit tests.

```
class HTTPRequestClient {

    private HTTPRequest httpRequest = HttpRequestFactory.getHttpRequest();

    public void callServer(){
        httpRequest.getRequest("http://someurl.com/");
    }

    void setHttpRequest(HTTPRequest httpRequest){
        this.httpRequest = httpRequest;
     }
  }

class HTTPRequestFactory {
   private static final HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();

   public static HTTPRequest getHttpRequest() {
     return httpRequest;
   }
}

class HTTPRequestClientTest {
     HTTPRequestClient  httpRequestClient;

       @Before
       public void setUp(){
           httpRequestClient = new HTTPRequestClient();
           httpRequestClient.setHttpRequest(new HttpRequestMock());
        }

        @Test
        ...
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. However, I will be having multiple HTTPRequestClients doing various things. I dont see the need of having creating multiple objects for HTTPRequest for each class.

Comment: You can create a `HTTPRequestFactory`. And you can control the creation of only one `HTTPRequest` object.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I will try it out. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation of **Dependency Injection** (without an Injection Framework) can be made **using setters**:

```
class SomeOtherClass {

    private HTTPRequest httpRequest;
    public void setHttpRequest(HTTPRequest httpRequest){

    }

    public void someAction(){
        httpRequest.getRequest(...);
    }
}

...
SomeOtherClass someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass(httpRequest);
```

In the example above, `HttpRequest` (the dependency) is injected into `SomeOtherClass`. This way, a unit test is able to create a Mock of `HttpRequest`, provide it to `SomeOtherClass` and test `SomeOtherClass` without its external dependencies.

Does that make sense ?

---

Now, **about singleton**: making HttpRequest a Singleton makes it harder to *Mock* (Using mock framework like Mockito). Plus, classes like SomeOtherClass are able to just do HttpRequest.getInstance() so your test can't do anything about it.

Comment: Yes I thought about this. But I don't want the responsibility of creating HttpRequest to be done by the person calling SomeOtherClass. How do I handle it in this case?

Comment: Then, you can use an Injection framework like Spring or Guice. The framework will instantiate the objects and inject them into your beans.

Comment: I was looking at the examples of Guice. So in this case where should the binding be done? Will someotherclass do the binding? Would it be possible for you to give an example.

Comment: Honestly, Injection framework isn't an easy concept to grasp at first and I feel you would be better serve to go through tutorials. Take a look at StackOverflow's documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/guice/3449/getting-started-with-guice#t=201701130255302041285  It shows a simple working solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Put an empty file named `beans.xml` into the `WEB-INF` directory.
- Annotate your `HttpRequest` class with `@ApplicationScoped`.
- Add local field to all classes using it, and annotate them with `@Inject`.